# Was the recent uncontrolled Chinese rocket de-orbit exceptional?

Tags: debris

The recent (April 2021) Chinese CZ-5B rocket launch gained widespread media attention because the large launcher was designed to de-orbit in an uncontrolled fashion, and ultimately landed in the Indian Ocean. This is the second such launch: in 2020, one crash-landed in West Africa. There has been some criticism of the apparent recklessness of this approach.

I asked a question on Law ([https://law.stackexchange.com/q/64802/31473](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64802/uncontrolled-rocket-re-entry-kills-my-dog-what-are-the-legal-consequences)) regarding the legal consequences around (hypothetical) personal or property damage caused by re-entering debris from this launch. One aspect I drew attention to was the apparent reckless nature of it (which often has an impact on a legal claim) - this is not re-entering debris from the early days, or a result of a fault. The post initially received criticism (now deleted) for singling out the Chinese, where the US might be considered at least as much a target (and SpaceX was mentioned). After all, most space junk is of US or Russian origin. Skylab was edited into the question for balance.

Which leads to the question: has the CZ-5B launch been unfairly singled out for criticism, or is this approach to debris management indeed more widespread? And is it reasonable to consider *rapidly re-entering launch debris* as a distinct case from space junk generally?

Comment: It is not an isolated incident. Although space debris have been found from the space launches originating from many different countries, China does seem to have rather a lot. For example see the report below in which Chinese rockets feature heavily. The majority but far from all of US debris appear washed up on beaches. https://pauldmaley.com/sd1/      https://news.finance.co.uk/chinese-rocket-crashed-small-town-near-xichang-satellite-launch-center/

Comment: https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-administrator-statement-on-chinese-rocket-debris

Comment: A rocket that gets into orbit on another stage will usually leave its stage in orbit with it. The stage would need to have an own engine and fuel to de-orbit controllably. The Space Shuttle did it differently: it went into a parking orbit with a perigee low enough for the External Tank to reenter the atmosphere, while the orbiter fired its own engines to go to a higher orbit. I dunno of any other spacecraft that did something like this, so I guess it is common that the upper stage remains in orbit.

Comment: Usually a launcher is careful about what happens to their rocket parts. For instance, Israel launches due west so it goes over the ocean instead of over neighboring countries. US paperwork includes a debris mitigation report -- you can't have chunks that can survive reentry, or if you do it has to be controlled. I can't give an authoritative answer but, while it's true that the US is responsible for a lot of debris in orbit, it's not common for big chunks to be hitting the ground at random.

Comment: CZ-5 is a "1.5-stage to LEO" design, so the part of the rocket that goes into LEO with the payload is quite big, so it's not a responsible to leave it in LEO after deploying the payload. They could just blow the rocket into pieces when altitude is low enough, or deploy a inflatable drag device and steer it into the ocean.

Comment: Accidentally I saw that particular piece flying over Sichuan China around 5:49 AM, 2020-05-09, Beijing Time when I was halfway summitting a mountain. After factoring out the possibility of a drone (too fast), an airplane (too quite), and a satellite (too bright and tumbling), I concluded it must be a rocket body and must be the Chinese CZ-5B. I (being Chinese) have to say China does have a bad reputation regarding spent rocket stages.

Comment: Scott Manley has a video on this, posted 5/8. Other instances of space junk de-orbiting and hitting the ground, like Skylab and a Russian space station, were unintentional and not desired. Apparently, China just doesn't care.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afGFmAljL5E

Answer (score 1):

To summarize:
While the US, much of Europe, and China have signed onto the 1967 Outer Space Treaty and 1972 Space Liability Convention if your property or person is damaged you would have to convince your politicians / embassies to invoke the provisions. Your country would have to be convinced to go to bat for you.

If you were hit by United States Government owned debris then you might be able to claim damages under the Federal Torts Claim Act.

There is an article written on this specific question:
https://www.planetary.org/articles/uncontrolled-reentry-rocket-damage-space-lawyers-explain

Comment: This might be a useful answer to the original Law.SE question linked above, but this question isn't about the law, it's about practice: whether the apparently cavalier stance on debris management shown by these launches is typical or unusual compared to other agencies around the world.